# Can the shell be more "offensive"?

Tags: shell, cowsay

My *Gentoo* Linux is compiled with the [*offensive*](http://www.calculate-linux.org/packages/flags/offensive) USE [flag](http://www.gentoo.org/dyn/use-index.xml) enabled:

```
# sudo su -
Password: 
Hold it up to the light --- not a brain in sight!
Password:
```

It is also possible to select [fortunes](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fortune&sektion=6&manpath=FreeBSD%206.4-RELEASE) based on the degree of offensiveness:

```
# fortune -o kernelcookies | cowsay -b
 _________________________________________ 
/ /* This is total bullshit: */           \
|                                         |
\ linux-2.6.6/drivers/video/sis/init301.c /
 ----------------------------------------- 
        \   ^__^
         \  (==)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Considering the list of flavored items<sup>1</sup> provided in the link is short - and I personally don't use a *molecular dynamics simulation package* - is there any more of that sort of spice in the **shell(s)** in Linux generally (or UNIX)?

---

<sup>1- It's good to remember that [`cowsay`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cowsay) can output any argument, not just fortunes, for instance the output of a command or script: `cowsay -s $(script_in_path_or_command)`. Note -s is just for the cow's appearance here, see manpages.</sup>

Comment: apt-get moo and aptitude moo  , aptitude moo -v , aptitude moo -vv and so on. but it's for Debian based.

Comment: @RenanVicente Note I use Gentoo. In my repo, the `moo` I have is dev-perl/Moo - Minimalist Object Orientation (with Moose compatiblity). Please be more precise.

Comment: There should be a special insult for every time you run `sudo su -`. Possibly it should just change the root password to `sudo -i`.

Comment: @illuminÉ `sudo -i` gives the root shell that you're using `sudo su -` to get. I was joking it should insult you for the roundabout way you're doing it.

Comment: @derobert Yes indeed it changes everytime...both commands. Thanks for explaining, I didn't know `sudo -i` was the same as `sudo su -`. Saves 1 char to type each time!

Comment: BTW, I thought of a way to do this in bash, using the same stunt I use to color the prompt based on exit code and also Ubuntu's command not found stuff... Will write up and post it once I get home.

Comment: Not too offensive, but in that kind of mood: `sl` - A steam locomotive runs across the screen if you type "sl" instead of "ls"

Comment: @Ouki Sure, "offensive" is really about humor and flavor and, because of the possible confusion with ls here, it's also about something unexpected happening in the shell... I couldn't find `sl` on Gentoo but the source is [here](http://www.tkl.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~toyoda/index_e.html). Cheers!

Comment: Well, I went to bed upon getting home so didn't get around to writing this until today... but posted as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, by using `PS1` and `command_not_found_handle`, it's possible to have bash insult you:

```
anthony@Watt:~$ . /tmp/insult.sh 
anthony@Watt:~$ sl
bash: sl: command not found, incompetent spoony bard
anthony@Watt:~$ ls /wrong/path
ls: cannot access /wrong/path: No such file or directory
Learn to type, second-rate Horrified Heron.
anthony@Watt:~$
```

And here is `/tmp/insult.sh` that I sourced in above.

```bash
### Data ###
bash_insulter_sentences=(
    'Have you considered Windows, %s?\n'
    'Learn to type, %s.\n'
    'Fell asleep at the keyboard again, %s?\n'
    "Failure is common when you're a %s, isn't it?\n"
)

bash_insulter_subjects=(
    'spoony bard'           # we all played this, right?
    'extra-Warty Warthog'
    'Dazed Drake'
    'Fidgety Fawn'
    'Horrified Heron'       # etc.
)

bash_insulter_adjectives=(
    'incompetent ' # these have built-in spacing
    'inept '
    'second-rate '
    '' # chance of none
    ''
)

### Functions to generate insults ###
bash_insulter_random_element() {
    if [ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -lt 4 ] || \
        [ ${BASH_VERSINFO[0]} -eq 4 -a ${BASH_VERSINFO[1]} -lt 3 ]; then
        # bash before 4.3 doesn't have -n
        eval "local var=(\"\${$1[@]}\")"
    else
        local -n var="$1"
    fi
    local len=${#var[@]}
    echo -n "${var[$RANDOM % len]}" # Slightly biased. Don't care.
}

bash_insulter_full_subject() {
    bash_insulter_random_element bash_insulter_adjectives
    bash_insulter_random_element bash_insulter_subjects
}

bash_insulter_do_insult() {
    printf "$(bash_insulter_random_element bash_insulter_sentences)" "$(bash_insulter_full_subject)"
}

### set up ###
command_not_found_handle() {
    echo "bash: $1: command not found, $(bash_insulter_full_subject)"
    return 127
}

PS1='`
    if [ 0 -ne $? -a 127 -ne $? ]; then
        bash_insulter_do_insult
    fi
    echo "\u@\h:\w\$ "; 
`'
```

Comment: @illuminÉ maybe you have an older version of bash, not sure when that feature was added. Does declare -n work?

Comment: I have 4.2.45(1)-release. It so happens I have tons of pkg to update. So I'll try this under Arch later! Thanks there, seems fun, I like the idea of mixing it up! Cheers!

Comment: @illuminÉ 4.3.0 here, how is it possible that Debian has a newer bash than Gentoo? Anyway, checking the NEWS file, it's a new feature in 4.3. I'll see about adding in a version that doesn't need the new feature.

Comment: @illuminÉ edited, will hopefully now work with bash 4.2.

Comment: Thank you, that's a blast really loll. Works great! But indeed Debian. I [checked](https://packages.gentoo.org/package/app-shells/bash) and indeed 4.3 hasn't made it yet. Oh, btw, I was more into Bard's tale lol.

Comment: Dear Torvalds this is *amazing*.

Answer (score 2):

Someone mentioned [`sl`](http://www.tkl.iis.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~toyoda/index_e.html). In software like an interpreter which aims at maximum predictability, *surprise* certainly qualifies as something "offensive" in context. The manual also lists appropriate options:

```
DESCRIPTION
   sl  is a highly advanced animation program for curing your bad habit of
   mistyping.

   -a     An accident is occurring. People cry for help.

   -l     Little version

   -F     It flies like the galaxy express 999.

   -c     C51 appears instead of D51.
```

...and an interesting *bug* :

```
BUGS
   It sometimes list directory contents.
```